# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $.templates is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I`m receiving the following error: **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $.templates is not a function**

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6NcZ.png)

I have 4 files:

1. MvcLayout.chstml (that contains the placeholders, scripts
   references and etc)
2. SearchResources.js (that contains the
   scripts reference for all files)
3. Rendering.js (contains the
   function that call the search.js, Using JsRender)
4. search.js (function to call
   Ajax using VUE and Axios)

The Jquery Reference is in MvcLayout.cshtml

[Reference of Jquerys Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSGBM.png)

Now if I duplicate the Jquery reference in my Search Resources.html, the $.templates works perfectly.

[With 2 Jquerys References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucupf.png)

Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: jsrender.js must be loaded after loading jquery. Your use of MvcLayout may be leading to an initial loading of jsrender.js before jquery has been loaded from the header.

Comment: Thanks man! I remove the JsRender reference from SearchResources.htm and put in MvcLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks man! I remove the JsRender reference from SearchResources.htm and put in MvcLayout.

For now the Jquery is being referenced before JsRender.